# How to update Adobe Flash Player in Kubuntu latest update

Tags: updates, adobe

I've been having problems with updating Adobe Flash Player. I downloaded the tar.gz but to be honest I'm completely lost from there.

Answer (score 7):

You should just install the latest version from the Ubuntu repositories. It is a lot easier and normally they keep this one up-to-date with new Linux Flash releases.

To install it run the command `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`

Comment: Once I've installed the installer, how do I run it?

Comment: After installing the flashplugin-installer package, it should work automatically in Firefox.

Comment: Linux Flash hasn't had an update, other than security patches, in years; many web sites that require Flash won't run with it, because they don't recognize version 11-something as current when Windows/Mac Flash is at version 17-something.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using Freshplayer rather than the flashplugin-installer package.  Freshplayer uses the (much newer, still updated) Windows Flash Player via Wine and API redirection in Firefox and SeaMonkey (probably in other Mozilla-based browsers as well, such as IceWeasel).  It updates within 2-3 days of new releases, so maintains security, and provides a Flash Player that appears up to date to web sites that block old/insecure Flash versions.  I've been using it for quite a while, and find it very stable.  It was also easy to install.

It does have the same hardware requirements as the current Windows Flash Player, so won't work on 32-bit processors made before about 2002, but most of those machines won't work well in Ubuntu anyway because of instruction set or RAM limitations.